# DataGridView corresponding Columns... With MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I want all the rows that are checked in the CheckColumn (Which I have named 'chk') for their corresponding 'ID' which is another column (column1)

I need this information to rum a MySQL Command to delete the checked users..

I don't know how to even start please help don't hate :)

Comment: *Bump. I know this is not a very well asked question but if you can be of any assistance it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with just the CheckColumn 'chk'. Instead, iterate through all the rows of the `DataGridView`, and find out if the value of the CheckColumn is true.

Here is an example that can hopefully get you started. Imagine you had a button click routine to delete all the checked rows. In this routine, as you go through each row in your `DataGridView`, store the rows that have a value of `True` for the CheckColumn into a `List`. In my example I'm assuming the ID column is the first column and the CheckColumn is the second one. You can adjust the array indices from my example to fit your needs or access the columns by name instead of index. For the rows that were checked, you can call a function which does your SQL transaction.

When you are done going through the entire `DataGridView`, go through the list of rows (that had a value of `True` for checked) that you have stored in your list and delete them from the `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    //Use a list to store all the rows you need to delete
    Dim RowsToDelete As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

    //Go through each row and find all the ones who's values are checked
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        //Assume column at index 0 is the ID and column at index 1 is the CheckColumn
        If row.Cells(1).Value = True Then
            DeleteRow(row.Cells(0).Value) //This will call your SQL stored procedure and pass it the ID
            RowsToDelete.Add(row)
        End If
    Next

    //Delete all the rows from the DataGridView that were checked
    For Each rowtodelete In RowsToDelete
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(rowtodelete)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRow(ByVal ID As Integer)
    //Call an SQL function here with the ID Value
    //To delete the record from the database
End Sub
```

You can probably make this perform better by storing the ID's in a table and passing the table as a value to your SQL procedure... I know you can do this in SQL Server 2008 but I'm not sure about MySQL. Also, if the SQL call takes a long time (it doesn't seem like it would in this case) you might want to consider running the SQL command on a separate thread than the user interface. But without jumping too far ahead, this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I try and use the mysql command and it says ID may result as null at runtime.

Comment: @Kraxed is it just a warning? if so, you can check if the id is not null before calling your sql function.